# How can I have a list in java with larger than integer space

Tags: java, list, indexing

I am using java.util.List in java for storing a results of my calculation

How can I store values for indexes bigger than maximum integer? (eg large)

Comment: Use multiple dimensions (e.g. 2D/3D array), and use math to convert from linear index to multidimensional index.

Comment: Are you asking how to store larger **values** in your ```List``` or are you asking how to store larger **amounts of elements** in your ```List```?

Comment: @CanadianDavid Seems to me that it's the latter -- "for indexes bigger than maximum integer"

Comment: If it's the former, that's going to be a huge list in memory. Let's say your results are all `int`s. Each `Integer` autoboxed value takes space: call it 8 bytes for the reference, 12 bytes for the object header, 4 bytes for the `int` value: 24 bytes per `int`. If you have `Integer.MAX_VALUE` of those, you're looking at about 48 gb of RAM right there.

Comment: What is your use-case? How big is your list?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, you will not be using the java.util.List interface.  You will have to implement something else.

If it was my program, and if it was not tailored for some specific supercomputing environment, then I would seriously consider using a database instead of trying to store more than two billion objects in RAM.

Comment: The question is how to store large numbers, not large amounts of data.

Comment: @AnubianNoob "for indexes bigger than maximum integer"

Answer (score 2):

The [FastUtil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) library, which specializes in huge data structures, has a [BigList](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/BigList.html) class whose implementation actually uses arrays of arrays.  Getters and setters take `long` parameters for indices.

> With fastutil 6, a new set of classes makes it possible to handle very
>   large collections: in particular, collections whose size exceeds 2^31.
>   Big arrays are arrays-of-arrays handled by a wealth of static methods
>   that act on them as if they were monodimensional arrays with 64-bit
>   indices, and big lists provide 64-bit list access.