# Data too big for int indexing

Tags: java, data-structures

Suppose I'm into Big Data (as in bioinformatics), and I've chosen to analyze it in Java using the wonderful Collections Map-Reduce framework on HPC. How can I work with datasets of more than `2 31 ^ 1 -` items? For example,

```
final List<Gene> genome = getHugeData();
profit.log(genome.parallelStream().collect(magic);
```

Comment: Of course not with a `List`, may be a `List<List>`? How are you reading your data?

Comment: You're gonna need a distributed solution here. Nobody loads a huge dataset into memory at once to analyze it, there's just not enough memory (not to mention the computation power required).

Comment: @Kayaman that is not true. There are schemes targeted on analyzing huge amounts of data in memory single machine with hundreds GB of RAM. And yes, 2^31 - 1 is quite feasible limit for that amount of memory (given that individual record size is a few bytes long).

Comment: @om-nom-nom you're right. But somehow I don't think the OP is working with one of those machines. And you still can't create an array bigger than Integer.MAX_VALUE in Java, even if you had the memory.

Comment: @Kayaman yeah, but you can fake it with multiple arrays (so underlying storage scheme would be more like 2d array)

Comment: I think he should look at the framework's documentation if there are suggested ways to deal with big data sets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025392/how-can-i-have-a-list-in-java-with-larger-than-integer-space

Comment: More than 2^31 items consumes a lot of RAM. Load it partially. Assuming that an item is only an Integer, it's 24 bytes per item (8 for the reference, 12 bytes for the object header, 4 bytes for the int value). 2^31 such Integer items will take 48 GB of RAM.

Comment: Remember a key part of the question...the OP wants to use Collections Map-Reduce against his data (which is why I didn't vote to close as a duplicate of the question I linked above). That could make some of the suggestions not very feasible.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk hypothetically, I have terabytes of memory. No problem. And good (and lots of) processors.

Comment: @Kayaman hypothetically, I have a ton of memory, etc. The actual question, I guess, is whether _Java_ can handle large datasets (especially with its map-reduce).

Comment: @SimonKuang - before you get too invested in this path, I would suggest doing a simple test with @om-nom-nom's approach. The reason is that there may be fundamental limitations built into Collections that prevent what you want to do. For instance, the Collection interface declares a method `size` that returns a value of type `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your data so it consists of many chunks -- once you're exceed 2 ^ 31 - 1 you're going to next one. Sketch is:

```
class Wrapper {
  private List<List<Gene>> chunks;
  Gene get(long id) {
    int chunkId = id / Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int itemId = id % Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    List<Gene> chunk = chunks.get(chunkId);
    return chunk.get(itemId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have multiple problems. How big your data is?

The simplest solution is to use another structure such as LinkedList which (only if you are interested in serial accesses) or a HashMap which may have a high insertion cost. A LinkedList does not allow any random access whatsoever. If you want to access the 5th element you have to access first all previous 4 elements as well.

Here is another thought:
Let us assume that each gene has an id number (long). You can use an index structure such as a B+-tree and index your data using the tree. The index does not have to be stored on the disk it can remain on the memory. It does not have much overhead as well.   You can find many implementations of it online.

Another solution would be to create a container class which would contain either other container classes or Genes. In order to achieve that both should implement an interface called e.g. Containable.  In that way both classes Gene and Container are Containable(s). Once a container reaches its max. size it can be inserted in another container and so on. You can create multiple levels that way.

I would suggest you look online (e.g. Wikipedia) for the B+-tree if u are not familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

An Array with 2^31 Objects would consume about 17 GB memory...

You schould store the data a Database.